# Prevent Pandas read_Excel / read_CSV from assigning (i.e. inferring) an index automatically

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-import

Total newbie and this is my first ever question so apologies in advance for any inadvertent faux pas.

I have a large(ish) dataset in Excel xlsx format that I would like to import into a pandas dataframe. The data has column headers except for the first column which does not have a header label. Here is what the excel sheet looks like:

[Raw data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wv5AG.jpg)

I am using read_excel() in Pandas to read in the data. The code I am using is:
`df = pd.read_excel('Raw_Data.xlsx', sheetname=0, labels=None, header=0, index_col=None)`

(I have tried index_col = false or 0 but, for obvious reasons, it doesn't change anything)

The headers for the columns are picked up fine but the first column, circled in red in the image below, is assigned as the index.

[wrong index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ohk0L.jpg)

What I am trying to get from the read_excel command is as follows with the index circled in red:

[correct index](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqIte.jpg)

I have other excel sheets that I have used read_excel() to import into pandas and pandas automatically adds in a numerical incremental index rather than inferring one of the columns as an index.

None of those excel sheets had missing label in the column header though which might be the issue here though I am not sure.

I understand that I can use the reset_index() command after the import to get the correct index.

Wondering if it can be done without having to do the reset_index() and within the read_excel() command. i.e. is there anyway to prevent an index being inferred or to force pandas to add in the index column like it normally does.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: In my testing, `.reset_index()` after import is your best bet. The closest I could get otherwise is `df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', usecols=range(1,99))`. But that ignores the unlabeled column entirely, which is not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thank you. You are correct that using usecols (1, 99) seems to omit the first column. That is not ideal as that column has data I need. Wondering if it  would it be possible to do usecols(0,99) but flag that column 0 should not be used as the index?

Comment: Not that I know of, sorry!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do it with only the read_excel function because of the missing value in cell A1.  If you want to insert something into that cell prior to reading the file with pandas, you could consider using openpyxl as below.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook as load

path = 'Raw_Data.xlsx'
col_name = 'not_index'
cell = 'A1'

def write_to_cell(path, col_name, cell):

    wb = load(path)

    for sheet in wb.sheetnames:
        ws = wb[sheet]
        if ws[cell].value is None:
            ws[cell] = col_name

    wb.save(path)
```

Comment: Thank you. It would work but not ideal as it requires modifying the excel file. It would work a lot better if there was a way to turn off the infer index functionality in read_excel or force adding in an index. Would be much more universal as well if there are multiple files that need to be uploaded.

Comment: Yes, agree completely.  It appears that functionality is not available presently.  Just thought this might be an option to consider.